# Why can I use javac & java without having JAVA_HOME set?

Tags: java, java-home

My Java version is :

```
java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
```

I don't set `JAVA_HOME` in my `~/.bash_profile`, but I can use both `javac` and `java`!

My `.bash_profile` looks like this:

```sh
export EDITOR="vim"
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion

export MAVEN_HOME="$HOME/opt/maven"
export PATH="$PATH:$MAVEN_HOME/bin"
```

If I want to install other version of the JDK like 11,14,15...., how can I use that? Do I need to set`JAVA_HOME`?

And if I have multiple versions of JDK installed at the same time, how can I use them at different times as needed? What I see on the Internet is to configure Java_ Home, I don't know what to do at all, because I'm worried that after I install several other versions of JDK, they won't work.

I use MacOS Big Sur.

Comment: Your shell doesn't care about `JAVA_HOME` to know where to find an executable.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`JAVA_HOME` is widely misunderstood.

Java itself (i.e. the `java`, `javac` and related executables) doesn't actually care about `JAVA_HOME`.

When they are executed they know which JDK to use (the one they are associated with). The only relevant thing is that your shell (or other tool) *finds* the executables in the first place and for this [`PATH` is used](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)). Note that `PATH` is a general-purpose variable used by basically all widely used general purpose OS today to find executables. It's *not* a Java-specific thing.

In other words: when launching `java` directly from the shell, only `PATH` is relevant.

So why does `JAVA_HOME` come up so frequently?

**Some** third-party tools (such as Gradle, Maven, Tomcat and various others) will use `JAVA_HOME` to find the appropriate JDK/JRE to execute. Most of the ones that do will fall back to whatever is on the `PATH` if no `JAVA_HOME` is set.

So **if** you use such a tool **and** you want to specify a specific Java version then you can set `JAVA_HOME` as an additional hint.

It might be a good idea to set `JAVA_HOME` to point to your preferred Java runtime, but it's not *necessary* for many things.

One commonly used pattern is to define a `JAVA_HOME` to point to your preferred JDK and then use that to set up your `PATH`. This way the two will be aligned and if the preferred JDK changes, you only need to change it in one point:

```sh
export JAVA_HOME="/some/path/pointing/to/a/jdk"
export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer made me aware of a question, Java_ Home is provided to other applications that rely on Java.

Answer (score 2):

I have had good experiences with [sdkman](https://sdkman.io/). You can easily install different JDKs and switch between them. All required environment variables will be set by sdkman!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Jenv](https://www.jenv.be/) which let you maintain different version of JDK and set `JAVA_HOME` dynamically.

You can also set specific Java version for different folder by having a file named `.java-version` and mention the java version.