# What is the value of $JAVA_HOME with gcr.io/distroless/java?

Tags: docker, distroless

What is the value of $JAVA_HOME with `gcr.io/distroless/java` images?

Comment: `docker run --rm -it --entrypoint env gcr.io/distroless/java:debug` doesn't show a `JAVA_HOME` and I don't know why it should be set: `java` is the entry point anyway. Just point it at the necessary jars. `JAVA_HOME` is [widely misunderstood](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69735512/why-can-i-use-javac-java-without-having-java-home-set) and not nearly as necessary as many people think.

Answer (score 0):

`$JAVA_HOME` is not defined for `gcr.io/distroless/java`.

Note, you can find the Java system files at `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/`.