# How to change java version within a bash script?

Tags: java, linux, bash

I have one piece of a script that needs a different java version to the rest of the script, up till now I've always manually changed versions with `sudo update-alternatives --config java` and then just select the one I need.

Is there a way to do that within a bash script?

I've tried `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java` which matches the path listed by `sudo update-alternatives --config java` but if I then type at the command line `java -version` it still lists the previous java version, and not java-11-openjdk-amd64.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean "when I type"? When you invoke a bash script that does some export, then the "parent" shell that you used to run the script won't see that export? Thus: please see [mcve] and add the relevant part of your code, instead of *explaining* what your code does.

Comment: When you type `java`, the value of `JAVA_HOME` is irrelevant. As with every command, the shell searches the `PATH` variable to located the executable. You can do a `type -a java` to see all the Java versions in your PATH, in search order.

Comment: [Strongly related to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69735512/why-can-i-use-javac-java-without-having-java-home-set/69735602#69735602). `JAVA_HOME` is quite misunderstood and not nearly as important as most people think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the tool used, but for most tools PATH is more important than JAVA_HOME.

Here is a script that changes the path and also restores it

```
#!/bin/bash
original_path=$PATH

java -version
export PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/:$PATH
java -version
export PATH=$original_path
java -version
```

If you directly need to invoke a specific java version a single time in your script then you could also do

```
PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/:$PATH java -version
```

Answer (score 0):

The commands
jdk8,
jdk11 or
jdk17

will change the version of java in git bash depending on what version you have installed.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).