# Where is Java's home; what to set JAVA_HOME to

Tags: java, scala, apache-kafka, jvm, java-home

I am trying to run a JVM service and it needs `JAVA_HOME` set.

`java` is on my `PATH`, but it's not clear what `JAVA_HOME` should be set to:

```
which java
/usr/bin/java
```

Comment: `readlink -f "$(which java)"` is what you need to show the real path. The value is the path without `/bin/java`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can I use javac & java without having JAVA\_HOME set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69735512/why-can-i-use-javac-java-without-having-java-home-set)

Comment: I feel the essence of `JAVA_HOME` has been missed: There are many JVM applications that, when built and bundled, ship with a wrapper launch/bootstrap script that have a hard dependency on `JAVA_HOME`; this shifts the responsibility to the user to resolve which Java to use in a very deliberate way; it does not matter how many versions and variants of Java you have installed (or merely downloaded and expanded), if `JAVA_HOME` is not set, the application/service will not start

Comment: I have run many JVM applications but have never encountered _any_ application that absolutely _needs_ JAVA_HOME set. I have many versions of Java installed, but I don't define JAVA_HOME. All applications (Gradle, Maven, IDEs, Kafka, Kotlin, etc) will use the `java` command from the PATH. The JAVA_HOME can be set as an _override_ if required.

Comment: @g00se that is cool, but don't think it's POSIX/portable? And not available on Windows, presumable?

Comment: @k314159 ... 'I apologize for the confusion in my previous responses' ;p if `JAVA_HOME` is not set, the Kafka launch script at least picks whatever `java` it can find.

Comment: @g00se just another note: `readlink` won't work on shims, as they are not symbolic links, but rather are scripts that - sometimes do some bootstrapping, then - delegate via `exec`

Comment: [readlink](http://gnu.org/software/coreutils) is a GNU utility, so no, not portable. As for shims, no, it won't work. But on Unix-based systems, `/usr/bin/java` is normally a link

Answer (score -1, accepted):

While `alternatives` may remain popular on *nix systems, I mostly use [jenv](https://www.jenv.be) and occasionally [sdkman](https://sdkman.io); they all introduce a level of indirection, if `/usr/bin/java` was not obscure enough.

If you are happy with the version of `java` on your `PATH` (`java -version`), you can query `java` directly for `java.home`:

```
java -XshowSettings:properties -version |& grep -Po '(?<=java.home = )(.*)'
```

This is not available in Java 6:

```
docker run --rm openjdk:6 java -XshowSettings:properties -version
Unrecognized option: -XshowSettings:properties
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

It is available since Java 7:

```
docker run --rm openjdk:7 bash -c "java -XshowSettings:properties -version |& grep -Po '(?<=java.home = |java.home=)(.*)'"
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-armhf/jre
```

For ease of use, create an alias:

```
alias java_home="java -XshowSettings:properties -version |& grep -Po '(?<=java.home = |java.home=)(.*)' "
```

#### Alternatives:

##### `jrunscript` or `jshell`

Some distributions provide `jrunscript` or `jshell`; these can be used to run Java code as script:

```
jrunscript -Dpolyglot.js.nashorn-compat=true -e 'java.lang.System.out.println(java.lang.System.getProperty("java.home"));'
```

or

```
jshell -J-Dpolyglot.js.nashorn-compat=true - <<<'java.lang.System.out.println(java.lang.System.getProperty("java.home"));'
```

Note this approach and these tools are old and should be considered deprecated.

##### Java as a Source Interpreter

Since [Java 11](https://openjdk.org/jeps/330) you can execute Java source code as a script directly on the `java` binary:

```
cat <<EOF > ./java-home
#! /usr/bin/java --source 11

public class JavaHome {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.home"));
    }
}
EOF

chmod u+x ./java-home

./java-home
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-arm64
```